# How to make scripts visible for import in PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3, import, path

This script imports the desired module when used outside of a PyQGIS  script in QGIS.

How to tell QGIS where to look for the scripts, if not with `sys.path.append()`?

```py
import sys
import os

try :
    import feature_switcher
except:
    print("raw import failed")

print(sys.path)

path_to_scripts = os.path.join('C:\\','Workplace','row_detector','src','qgis')
print(path_to_scripts)
sys.path.append(path_to_scripts)
try :
    import feature_switcher
except:
    print("import with added Windows_style sys.path also failed")

path_to_scripts = 'C:/Workplace/row_detector/src/qgis/'
print(path_to_scripts)

sys.path.append(path_to_scripts)

try :
    import feature_switcher
except:
    print("import with added Unix_style sys.path also failed")
```